# Pandas: Find if the full name, acronym, or both listed in a separate data frame is present in a column in a data frame and add a column of acronyms

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list, contains

I have a pandas data frame that include full names and acronyms of assessment names called names_df.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4ZGf.png)

I also have another data frame that has the information of how to use these assessments called uses_df.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/24hh1.png)

I want to check if the full names or acronyms or both) from name_df appear in uses_df, and add a new column to the uses_df that includes the list of assessments appeared in the "uses" column text in ACRONYMS even when only the "full name" appeared in the text, or both "full name" and "acronym" appeared in the text. Also, when the same assessment names/acronyms appear more than once in the text, it only return once.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9kwf.png)

I have tried a couple of different things using "str.contains" etc. but having a trouble making it work. The real data can be much larger than the above example.

Comment: Paste your code as an "Edit" along with a sample query of your data and what shoud result from the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to extract both `Assessment_Name` and `acronym`:

```
import re

# Build the regex pattern
names = '|'.join(re.escape(name) for name in names_df['Assessment_Name'])
acronyms = names_df['acronym'].str.cat(sep='|')
pattern = fr"\b({acronyms}|{names})\b"

# Transform Assessment_Name to acronym
dmap = names_df.set_index('Assessment_Name')['acronym']

# Extract strings then apply above transformation
# and finally get unique acronyms for each row
out = (uses_df['uses'].str.extractall(pattern).replace(dmap)
          .reset_index(level=0).set_axis(['index', 'acronym'], axis=1)
          .drop_duplicates().groupby('index').agg(list))

uses_df['assessment_appeared'] = out
```

Output:

```
>>> uses_df
                                    uses assessment_appeared
0                  AN1 and AN7 were used          [AN1, AN7]
1        Assessment Name 2 (AN2) is used               [AN2]
2  Assessment Name 6 were useful for xyz               [AN6]

>>> pattern
\b(AN1|AN2|AN3|AN4|AN5|AN6|AN7|Assessment\ Name\ 1|Assessment\ Name\ 2|Assessment\ Name\ 3|Assessment\ Name\ 4|Assessment\ Name\ 5|Assessment\ Name\ 6|Assessment\ Name\ 7)\b
```

Comment: Thank you! I wish I could code like this - especially how you use the regex (someday!). When I try this with my actual dataset, I get the "ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 4 elements, new values have 2 elements" for the "out =" part of the code. Any idea why?

Comment: Which line causes this error?